# Maintain file name from web response

Tags: c#

I have a web service named grabFile and when I call it it gets the path and file name to a file and returns it to me as a `Stream`.  The web service sets the file name by adding the `content-Disposition` header.  When a request is made through my service I take the response and return it.  The issue is when calling the grabFile web service directly(e.g. placing the address seen in my web request below directly into my browsers address bar) the file is downloaded and the file has the correct file name.  However when I call the web service from my program and pass the stream along it downloads the file but with a default file name.  Is there away to just pass the response headers along with the stream when I return it from my application?

```
private Stream GetFileStream(string fileName)
{
    string requestId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper();
    string uriTemplate = String.Format("https://www.example.org/grabfile/grabfile.svc/file/myapp/?q={0}&rid={1}",fileName,requestId);
    Uri uri = new Uri(uriTemplate);
    WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri);
    WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();

    return webResponse.GetResponseStream();

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by '...when calling the grabFile web service directly...'? What does the word 'directly' refer to in that sentence?

Comment: I clarified what I mean by calling the web service directly in my question

Comment: Not sure if I understand but Stream does not have a definition of 'filename' so you may wanto to append that to header or change the return type. Also MVC Controllers have a `FileContentResult` for returning a file like `return File(Stream, content-type, filename);`

Comment: One thing to note: `WebResponse` implements `IDisposable` and therefore its usage (in this case, just the `return` statement) should be wrapped in a `using` construct to ensure proper deterministic disposal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `GetResponseStream()` method returns a stream containing only the body of the response. You can use the `Headers` property in order to get the `Content-Disposition` header value and then parse it:

```
string fileName = webResponse.Headers["Content-Disposition"].Replace("attachment; filename=", String.Empty).Replace("\"", String.Empty);
```

(You might need to adjust the replace to your header value)

So you can create yourself an entity to hold the result of your request, for example something like this:

```
public class ResponseFileInfo
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Stream Content { get; private set; }

    public ResponseFileInfo(string name, Stream content)
    {
        Name = name;
        Content = content;
    }
}
```

And have a method like this:

```
private ResponseFileInfo GetFile(string fileName)
{
    string requestId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper();
    string uriTemplate = String.Format("https://www.myDomain.com/grabfile/grabfile.svc/file/myapp/?q={0}&rid={1}&sid={2}",fileName,requestId,this.sid);

    MemoryStream fileContent = null;
    string fileName = String.Empty;

    Uri uri = new Uri(uriTemplate);
    using (WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri))
    {
        using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            fileName = webResponse.Headers["Content-Disposition"].Replace("attachment; filename=", String.Empty).Replace("\"", String.Empty);

            fileContent = new MemoryStream();
            Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
            byte[] responseBuffer = new byte[16*1024];
            int responseBytesRead;

            while((responseBytesRead = responseStream.Read(responseBuffer, 0, responseBuffer.Length) > 0)
                fileContent.Write(responseBuffer, 0, responseBytesRead);
        }
    }

    return new ResponseFileInfo(fileName, fileContent);
}
```

You also need to remember to call `.Dispose()` on `ResponseFileInfo.Content` when you are done (I would consider implementing `IDisposable` in `ResponseFileInfo` and wrapping it in `using` block).